# How could I create a package in Julia and open source it?

Tags: deep-learning, julia

I am not a professional programmer but I want to create an small Julia machine learning package which is called neural spline flows. These networks are invertible neural networks which are mostly used to estimate an integral using the Monte Carlo method. I want to use this package as my scientific resume. The models are basically created using Flux or Knet. 
But the problem is that I am not satisfied with what I do. My codes are ugly and don't look like the ones written by professional programmers. 
Should I focus on learning some advanced aspects of Julia before creating my package? I don't want to waste my time.

Comment: About your last point: just make sure that the code works as advertised and that you have a really nice readme, documentation, introduction for non-experts, etc. You should be able to do that since _you_ are the expert. That's more important than internals, since not so many people will read the actual code. And then be open for issues and feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Julia ships with its own package manager call `Pkg`. The documentation takes you through the steps from starting a package from scratch all the way through adding tests and registering it with the general registry (which will allow other users to just `pkg> add YourPackage` from the Julia package manager).

You can find it here: https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/creating-packages/

There are also user packages that help with creating packages, examples include

- [PkgSkeleton.jl](https://github.com/tpapp/PkgSkeleton.jl) - as the name suggests, a very "bare bones" approach to get up and running quickly
- [PkgTemplates.jl](https://github.com/invenia/PkgTemplates.jl) - more fully featured, but as the Readme says currently in a state of restructuring.

Generally the bar for creating packages in Julia for new users is pretty low I would say (although my experience in other languages is limited!), which is probably one of the great strengths of the ecosystem.

And to address your worries about the "look" of your code: I wouldn't worry about it too much, if you want to share your code for others to use what matters in the first instance is the API and whether it is user friendly. The difference between your code and what you perceive to be "professional" code should only matter to the extent that your code is less performant because of a suboptimal coding style - but I don't think that should keep you from publishing a package, if others find it useful and notice obvious performance issues they might even help you fix them and thereby improve your package, which is the whole idea of open source!